# Xamarin forms linked data not visible

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

I have a Xamarin Forms project that contains physicians and related physician types.  The physician model contains the basic physician data along with a physiciantypeId.  The physiciantype model contains the related physiciantype.  I am able to get a listview that contains the physician, but the physiciantype does not show up in the listview.  Why is the data from the linked physiciantype not visible?

Physician Model

```
public class Physician
{
    
    public int PhysicianId { get; set; }
    public Guid? UniqueId { get; set; }
    public string Physician1 { get; set; }
    public bool Active { get; set; }
    public DateTime ActiveEndDate { get; set; }
    public string UId { get; set; }
    public byte[] Image { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public int PhysicianTypeId { get; set; }
    public PhysicianType PhysicianType1 { get; set; }

    
}
```

PhysicianType Model

```
public class PhysicianType
{
    public int PhysicianTypeId { get; set; }
    public string PhysicianType1 { get; set; }
}
```

DataService

```
class SxCaseDataService
{
    private readonly string Url = "http://10.0.0.19:3428/api/physicians/";
   

    public async Task<ObservableCollection<Physician>> GetPhysicians()
    {
        var httpClient = new HttpClient();

        var json = await httpClient.GetStringAsync(Url);

        var physicians = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ObservableCollection<Physician>>(json);

        return physicians;
    }
}
```

HomeViewModel

```
public class HomeViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{


    private ObservableCollection<Physician> _physicians;
    private SxCaseDataService _sxCaseDataService = new SxCaseDataService();
    private bool _isRefreshing;


    public ObservableCollection<Physician> Physicians
    {
        get => _physicians;
        set
        {
            _physicians = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }
    

    public bool IsRefreshing
    {
        get { return _isRefreshing; }
        set
        {
            _isRefreshing = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    public ICommand RefreshCommand => new Command(async () => { await GetPhysicians(); });

    public HomeViewModel()
    {

        GetPhysicians();
    }

    

    private async Task GetPhysicians()
    {
        IsRefreshing = true;

        Physicians = await _sxCaseDataService.GetPhysicians();
        

        IsRefreshing = false;
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }

}
```

}

HomeView

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
         xmlns:viewModels="clr-namespace:QiX2021TEST.ViewModels;assembly=QiX2021TEST"
         x:Class="QiX2021TEST.Views.HomeView"
         Title="Physicians">
<ContentPage.BindingContext>
    <viewModels:HomeViewModel/>
</ContentPage.BindingContext>
<StackLayout >
    <ListView x:Name="MainListView"
              ItemsSource="{Binding Physicians, Mode=TwoWay}" 
              CachingStrategy="RecycleElement"
              IsPullToRefreshEnabled="True"
              IsRefreshing="False"
              SeparatorVisibility="Default"
              HasUnevenRows="True">

                
                <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <ViewCell >
                            <StackLayout Padding="10" >

                                
                               
                                <Label  Text="{Binding Physician1, Mode=TwoWay}" />
                                <Label Text="{Binding PhysicianType1, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
                                        

                            </StackLayout>

                        </ViewCell>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListView.ItemTemplate>
                
    </ListView>

</StackLayout>
```

json

[json](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zoIgU.jpg)

Comment: **if** your data is being deserialized correctly (have you verified?) your binding expression should be "PhysicianType1.PhysicianType1".  Also, `TwoWay` binding on a Label is pointless, as the user cannot update a Label

Comment: @Jason I am able to view the data as expected from the api using Postman.  Changing the binding expression does not work because PhysicianType1 is part of the binding context of Physicians while PhysicianType1.PhysicianType1 is not.  I wonder if the problem is with the models?  Two was is just a remnant of trying different options.

Comment: viewing the data in Postman is NOT the same as deserializing it correctly in your app.  You need to use the debugger to validate that your app is deserializing the data correctly.

Comment: and `PhysicianType1` is a property on your model that returns a `PhysicianType` object.  That object ALSO has a `PhysicianType1` property that returns a `string`.  You want to display that `string` in your `Label`, so "PhysicianType1.PhysicianType1" is the correct path

Comment: @Jason I used the debugger.  The service is not returning anything from PhysicianType but I'm not sure why.

Comment: You haven't posted any code from your service so I can't help.

Comment: @Jason I posted it under DataService class SxCaseDataService.

Comment: What does the json look like?

Comment: @Jason I added a breakpoint to the var physicians = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ObservableCollection<Physician>>(json); to look at the json and it returns all of the fields expected including the physiciantype.  I also set a breakpoint at return physicians; and physicians shows PhysicianType1 as null, but returns the other fields.

Comment: Could you show your json string ? Whether some of your fields did not match and therefore did not convert successfully.

Comment: @LeoZhu-MSFT  is this what you are asking for? [
  {
    "physicianId": 0,
    "physicianTypeId": 0,
    "physician1": "string",
    "active": true,
    "physicianType": "string"
  }
]

Comment: @Brady Yes,but your json string  you gave above seems not match to your model.Try to change like below.

Answer (score 0):

Physician Model:

```
public class Physician
  {

    public int PhysicianId { get; set; }
    public Guid? UniqueId { get; set; }
    public string Physician1 { get; set; }
    public bool Active { get; set; }
    public DateTime ActiveEndDate { get; set; }
    public string UId { get; set; }
    public byte[] Image { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public int PhysicianTypeId { get; set; }
    public PhysicianType PhysicianType { get; set; }    //the key in your json string you gave above,its name is physicianType not PhysicianType1. 
 }
```